# Regex - Match a pattern

Tags: regex

I've to match this pattern:

3BxFxxx131xxxx

Where "x" stand for a character that is not needed to be matched.
Is possibile to match a string with this pattern?

I'm forced to use a concatenaion of "/^.{2}B/" for every position or exist a better solution?

Thank you

Comment: You probably are lookng for capturing groups, `^(.{2}).(.).{3}(.{3}).{4}$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/i3glg3/1)).

Comment: Can you be more specific of what "x" can stand for. Any character is very broad.

Comment: @JvdV: alphanumerics

Comment: The very basic form i'm using for what i need is this regex. 

"3B.F...131" ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/1))

Seem a bit poor, but it's working, since i know the exact number of "x". 
It work but Could be improveded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment, "x" stands for any alphanumeric char. In that case you could try:

```
^(?!.*_)3B\wF\w{3}131\w{4}$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/k6AGmq/9)

- `^`  - Start string anchor.
- `(?!.*_)` - Negative lookahead to prevent underscore anywhere in the string.
- `3B` - Match "3B" literally.
- `\w` - A single word-character. Shorthand for `[0-9A-Za-z_]`.
- `F` - Match "F" literally.
- `\w{3}` - Three word-characters.
- `131` - Match "131" literally.
- `\w{4}` - Four word-characters.
- `$` - End string anchor.